# Return array in construct method in php

Tags: php, arrays, class, constructor

I am trying to create a homepage where I will output question with its answers

I have a question which has 3 answers, but when I create the object it only return 1 answer, whereas I need it to return the array of answers. Do I need to create additional class answers in order to do that?

My code:

```
    include("connect-database.inc.php");

    $question_query = "SELECT
        questions.questionID,
        answers.answer,
        questions.question,
        questions.feedback,
        questions.mark,
        questions.questionTypeID 
    FROM questions 
    JOIN answers ON questions.questionID=answers.questionID";
    
    $questionList=array();
    $answerList = array();
    try {
        $mysqliResult = $link->query($question_query);
        while($var=$mysqliResult->fetch_assoc()){
            $questionList[$var['questionID']]=new questions($var['question'],$var['feedback'], $var['mark'], $var['questionTypeID'], $var['answer']);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        echo "MySQLi Error Code: " . $e->getCode() . "<br />";
        echo "Exception Msg: " . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }   
    var_dump($questionList);


    class questions {

        public function __construct($question, $feedback, $mark, $questionTypeID, $answerList){
            $this->question = $question;
            $this->feedback = $feedback;
            $this->mark = $mark;
            $this->questionTypeID = $questionTypeID;
            $this->answers($answerList);
        }

        public function answers($answers) {
            $answers = array();
            $this->answers = $answers;
        } 
    }
```

I have tried to change to query and retrieve data by answerID, but then I get the same question 3 times. Can anybody help with the solution?

Comment: What is the goal of `$answers = array();` inside `answers()` method? You overrides the given parameter, to store an empty array.

Comment: you are doing inner join that's why the number of data is repeating. first try to understand the difference between inner join and left join

Comment: What's the purpose of that useless try-catch? Did you know that this is a very bad practice as this exposes sensitive information to your users?

Comment: By using `$questionList[$var['questionID']] = new`, you override previous results with the key `$var['questionID']`.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to do `$questionList[$var['questionID']][] = new questions`

Comment: I think you have to create a `new Question` (if not already exists). And then append the answers in the previously created object (according to `questionID`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate new Question instance creating from add new answers to existing Question like:

```
$question_query = "SELECT
        questions.questionID,
        answers.answer,
        questions.question,
        questions.feedback,
        questions.mark,
        questions.questionTypeID 
    FROM questions 
    JOIN answers ON questions.questionID=answers.questionID";
    
    $questionList = [];
    try {
        $mysqliResult = $link->query($question_query);
        while ($var = $mysqliResult->fetch_assoc()) {
            if (!isset($questionList[$var['questionID']])) {
                $questionList[$var['questionID']] = new Question(
                    $var['question'],
                    $var['feedback'], 
                    $var['mark'], 
                    $var['questionTypeID']
                );
            }
            $questionList[$var['questionID']]->addAnswer($var['answer']);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        // debug only:
        echo "MySQLi Error Code: " . $e->getCode() . "<br />";
        echo "Exception Msg: " . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }   
    var_dump($questionList);


    class Question {

        public function __construct($question, $feedback, $mark, $questionTypeID) {
            $this->question = $question;
            $this->feedback = $feedback;
            $this->mark = $mark;
            $this->questionTypeID = $questionTypeID;
        }
        
        public function addAnswer($answer) {
            $this->answers[] = $answer;
        }
    }
```

[PHPize - online PHP environment](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/7092caace4168a6d5654a49a92d59228/php/php81/5666daec3039c173280a12469c8867fa/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use separate queries for both question and answer.

If you want to use `group by answerID`, of course it will return result with multiple answer with same question. Mysql return result as flat. Just save the value inside an array as such

```
$array[questionID]['answer'][] = $var['answer'];
```

Then you build the class object by looping through each `questionID`.